# Know which index caused an error during a bulk INSERT or bulk UPDATE in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, error-handling

When I INSERT or UPDATE a list of rows in PostgreSQL and one of them is causing an error, how can I know which one exactly (its index in the input list) ?

For example, if I have a UNIQUE constraint on the `name` column, and if name `two` already exists, I want to know that the constraint violation is caused by the input row at index `1`.

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name) VALUES ('0000', 'one'), ('0001', 'two');
```

I know PostgSQL will stop on the first error encountered, and therefore that we can't know all of the problematic rows. That's fine, I just need the first problematic index (if any).

Inserting each row separately is not a possibility since we want to optimize for performance as well.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't print the primary key of any rows that might be involved - there might be zero or more than one. If you are just trying to efficiently import a batch of rows which might have duplicates or other problems, you probably want to ask that as a question.

Comment: I'm assuming here that you aren't actually interested in the constraint name causing the problem because PostgreSQL prints that to your screen if you try this in psql and presumably whatever client library you are using gives you access to the error details too if you ask it to.

Comment: PostgreSQL already returns the constraint name that was violated. What I want is the index of the row in the input list that caused the violation (the first index, not all of them, if there are more than one)

Answer (score 1):

Postgres gives you the exactly what you are asking for and actually. It provides the constraint name, the column(s), and the value(s). However, much of this is is subsequent details to the error message. You need to extract the complete message. See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b79889735ed2fb36a3a4291a7ddde500).

Comment: It looks like we can get the value that is causing the constraint violation by parsing the string in the "detail" field of the error map. That's better, but still not exactly the index of the input row that is causing the constraint violation